# Telerik MVC TreeView get all checked node values

Tags: jquery, treeview, telerik-mvc

I Have a TreeView with ShowCheckBox(true). How can get all values of checked nodes in second level with JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about jQuery selectors:

To retrieve the values of the checked checkboxes only for the second level as array you can use the following line of code.

```
var array = $('#TreeViewName>ul>li>ul>li>div :checked').map(function(){ return this.value});
```

To get the text of a node or the value you should use the corresponding method - **getItemText** or **getItemValue**

There are example in the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-treeview-client-api-and-events.html#getItemText) :

```
var treeview = $('#ProductsTreeView').data('tTreeView');
var nodesSecondLevel= $("#TreeView1>ul>li :has(>div :checked)");
var arrayOfValue = nodesSecondLevel.map(function(){
    return treeview.getItemValue(this);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, But I want value of node not checkbox.